# NEXT.js - Globally imported styles in custom _app.js page don't work in server side rendering

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

When styles are globally imported into _app.js (As the Next js [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support) says) and the first page load is done, the server-side response comes without styles.

I have made use of [this repository](https://github.com/JakubChm/nextjs-mdbreact) and have modified it so that the new Nextjs feature, `Built-In CSS Support`, can be used.

In order for Next js to take over the styles, I have removed the legacy dependencies `next-compose-plugins`, `next-fonts` and `next-images` and have removed the `next.config.js` file.

### To reproduce

```
git clone https://github.com/turrione/nextjs-mdbreact.git
yarn install
yarn dev
```

Notice that when a request is made, the response preview is unstyled.

[Unstyled response preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb2MO.png)

The only way I have managed to fix the error is by adding the styles directly in the Head component of next-head

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { MDBContainer } from 'mdbreact';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import Footer from './Footer';

function Layout(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        {/* HARDCODING STYLES */}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.0/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      </Head>
      <NavBar />
      <MDBContainer>{props.children}</MDBContainer>
      <Footer />
      <style jsx global>{`
        #__next {
          min-height: 100vh;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: space-between;
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

Now you can see how the server side response comes with styles.

Is there a way to import the css files into the custom _app.js file (as the Nextjs documentation says) and get stylized pages from server-side?

[Styled response preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n05l7.png)

Comment: why don't you put this in the top level folder styles/global.css ?

Comment: Hola ZEE, According to the next js documentation to import the styles of .css files globally, it is necessary to import them into _app.js. It is not necessary to create a styles folder to add the css files. In fact, in some of the examples that zeit provides (see example with tailwind, wordpress etc), the same error can be reproduced. The server response comes without styles.